# Install a list of packages and replace all errors

Tags: apt, package-management

I have [a list of packages](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rubo77/bd9183fe2794467f482c/raw/5342531410a31513f827a2b8050e569e57870b66/gistfile1.txt) I would like to install on a fresh Ubuntu. Since those is a quite old list, I would like so see the outcome, If I would replace the suggestions automatically.

So all packages that are referenced to a newer other package shoud be auto-resolved and missing packages should be auto ignored.

Is there such an option like `apt-get install --fix-all`

Then I could install it with

```
url=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rubo77/bd9183fe2794467f482c/raw/5342531410a31513f827a2b8050e569e57870b66/gistfile1.txt
echo $(wget $url -qO -|xargs) > /tmp/pkglist
sudo apt-get install $(cat /tmp/pkglist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`. Aptitude, unlike `dpkg` and `apt-get` continues while ignoring errors. It still prints them but it continues.

I do this all the time myself for re-installing Ubuntu.

The command to use would be:

```
sudo aptitude update && cat pkglist | xargs sudo aptitude install
```

All you would have to do is replace `cat pkglist` with your `wget` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dpkg to install the list of packages.

First, you need to set the list of selected packages.

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < filename
```

where filename is the name of the file which contains the list of packages.

Then, update and install.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

This method only adds and upgrades packages, it will not remove packages that do not exist in the list.

Comment: That gives a lot of errors. And the question is about these. Try it with my list

Comment: Can you mention or post the errors that you are getting?

Comment: The same you would get. Many of those packages  don't exist any more